# JAXB - While generating the xml can we check the value of the object before generating

Tags: java, jaxb

Suppose i have an object

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "publisher")
class Person
{
 @XmlElement(required = true)
 int id;
 @XmlElement(required = true)
 String name;
}
```

I want to generate like

```
<person>
<id>1</id>
<name>test</name>
</person>
```

Suppose if the name is test10 I dont want that item in my xml. Anyways to implement this.

Comment: if (!"test10".equals(person.getName()) { marshaller.marshal(person);}. Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you want to skip just the name element or the complete person/publisher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

**Use Case #1 - Not Marshal Person Object Based on Name Element**

***If Person is Root Object***

If `Person` is the root object then you can do the following as suggested by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) in the comments on this question.

```
if (!"test10".equals(person.getName()) { 
    marshaller.marshal(person);
}
```

**If Person is a Referenced Object**

If `Person` is not the root object then you could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  It would look something like the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class PersonAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Person, Person> {

    @Override
    public Person unmarshal(Person person) throws Exception {
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public Person marshal(Person person) throws Exception {
       if(mull == person || "test10".equals(person.getName()) {
           return null;
       }
       return person;
    }

}
```

The `XmlAdapter` is specified using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  This annotation can be configured at the field/property, type, and package levels.  For examples see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html (field/property)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html (type)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html (package)

**Use Case #2 - Not Marshal Name Element Based On its Value**

If you just want to avoid marshalling the name element based on its value then again you could use an `XmlAdapter`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class NameAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
       if("test10".equals(string) {
           return null;
       }
       return string;
    }

}
```

Your `Person` class would look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "publisher")
class Person
{
 @XmlElement(required = true)
 int id;
 @XmlElement(required = true)
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NameAdapter.class)
 String name;
}
```

Comment: +1. I've learnt something new. Doesn't the last adapter conflict with the fact that name is required? Using it would lead to invalid XML, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JBNizet - Thank you for the up vote.  You are correct that the last adapter would allow you produce a document that was invalid to the XML schema that would be generated from the annotated classes.  Whether or not that is a problem depends on the users application.  Many people do not perform schema validation, and view an XML schema more as a guideline than a strict set of rules.